# Wordpress perm links

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Whenever I set the permanent links on wordpress to something other than the default

```
p=123
```

The links go to 404 pages

For example:

```
http://thewebsite.com/i/blog/2012/05/sample-post/
```

Would be linked as the blog post, but it would take you to a 404 result.

What can cause this kind of issue?

Comment: Are you doing list local system or on server ?

Comment: @AjayPatel local through wamp

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a rewrite in place. 
In the root of your website, create a `.htaccess` file. This will be a hidden file but if you are using Filezilla as a FTP program you will be able to view it.

Put in it this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Save it in the root of your website, ie, where wp-config goes and it should work. 
If you have your website in a sub directory you will need to change the Rewrite base to reflect this instead of / for root.

Hope this helps!

Comment: WordPress can manage the rewrite rules itself. If the issue were that WordPress could not write to the htaccess file there would be a message indicating the file is not writable.